# Converting Excel to JSON using Dataweave in anypoint studio

Tags: mule

Need to transform Excel to JSON using Dataweave in Anypoint Studio.

Mule Datamapper supports converting Excel files to JSON directly,where as in DataWeave it won't support Excel to JSON conversion.

In a blog i found that using POI libraries we can do this but it is a bit complex work.

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Excel (XLSX files) support for [DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave) (the data transformation processor) has been released with the new Anypoint Studio 6.1.2 version w/3.8.2 Runtime.

Please see how to use it here: [Excel format in DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-formats#excel)

And the release notes below:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/anypoint-studio-6.1-with-3.8.2-runtime-update-site-2-release-notes

Comment: I donno why this is down voted. @fermelon was correct

Comment: Works perfectly without any POI code using DataWeave! Thanks @Sahal for pointing it out in the comment, otherwise I would have implemented it using POI... saved me some time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any Excel transformer in 3.7 unless you want to use DataMapper which is deprecated. Yes, some work but you can use Apache POI like below -

1. Convert Excl to CSV using Java Transformer - I found this apache sample generic class [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/ss/ToCSV.java)
2. Now, Once you have the CSV, send that to DataWeave and do your CSV to JSON transformation.

Comment: Can't we convert Excel to JSON directly using the Java Transformer using POI libraries?

Comment: POI doesn't support reading/writing JSON. You can read the Excel using POI and then you would need to use another libraries like Jackson, GSON etc to convert that to JSON format. If you write your json transformation in java transformer then that transformer might become too specific to on transformation only. I would suggest to just create a java transformer to convert excel to csv (it will be reusable then). Once you have CSV, then use DataWeave to transform it to required JSON format. Writing DataWeave code would be easy than writing custom Jackson/GSON code, IMO.