# XLS to CSV using Mulesoft

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I have an XLS file, and i need to convert the data of it for CSV. The problem is: Seems like the newer versions of the Mule-studio does not support Excel files.

What's the better way to handle the data inside of it, since the dataMapper is not available anymore (and it used to work with xls files...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786039/converting-excel-to-json-using-dataweave-in-anypoint-studio)

Comment: Thank you. Used the deprecated connector, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Excel (XLSX files) support for [DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave) (the data transformation processor) has been released with the new Anypoint Studio 6.1.2 version w/3.8.2 Runtime.

Please see how to use it here: [Excel format in DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-formats#excel)

And the release notes below:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/anypoint-studio-6.1-with-3.8.2-runtime-update-site-2-release-notes

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is to Convert the excel file to JSON through java code and then convert the JSON to CSV. I know this is a work around but its limitation of mule too.